# Navigation drawer item background changed unexpectedly when updating to gradle:2.2.0-alpha2

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, navigation-drawer

Today I updated Android Studio from 1.5 to 2.2 and when I ran my app on a Nexus 4 with KitKat, without making any changes to google design or appcompat library, and clicked on an item in the navigation drawer its background changed unexpectedly.

This is how it's been render in devices pre-lollipop:
[image: This is how it's being rendered in devices pre-lollipop]

On lollipop devices, the background it's rendering correctly when clicking on a navigation item.

This is my app `build.gradle`

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

And this is my project `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha2'
}
```

## EDIT

I changed `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha2'` for `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'` and it renders as expected, without showing those black lines

Comment: try `Build > Clean`

Comment: @momo please check my edit

Comment: so you've answered your own question?

Comment: i think it should be 2.10

Comment: Same issue; hopefully this gets fixed with the next Gradle alpha version.